# Debug Assertion Failed on cout function

Tags: c++, debugging

In my code, I have a couple of places an identical `cout` function, which I decided to move outside of the `int main()`.
When I did this however and re-ran my code, when the function in question was triggered, I received a "Debug Assertion Failed" error.

**the code which I have placed outside the main function.**

```
string printresult(double smallest, double largest)
{
    cout << "the smaller value is: " << smallest << "\n";
    cout << "the larger value is: " << largest << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I believe it has something to do with the `return 0` code, which I have added at the end of my `cout` function, without it however, my code does now even compile. Can anyone point me towards to right direction, so that I can better identify my error?

**my full code**

```
#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h"

// conversion of units to meters

double funconvert(double x, string unit)
{
    const double cm_m = 1.0 / 100.0, in_cm = 2.54, ft_in = 12;
    if (unit == "m")
        return x = x;
    else if (unit == "cm")
        return x = x * cm_m;
    else if (unit == "in")
        return x = x * in_cm * cm_m;
    else if (unit == "ft")
        return x = x * ft_in * in_cm * cm_m;
    else
        cout << "Unknown unit value.\n";
}

// printing the large and the small variables
string printresult(double smallest, double largest)
{
    cout << "the smaller value is: " << smallest << "\n";
    cout << "the larger value is: " << largest << "\n";
    return 0;
}

int main() 
{
    vector<double>numbers;
    double a, b, smallest, largest;
    string unit;
    cout << "Please enter an intiger followed by a measurment unit [e.g 10cm]:";

    // Take input
    while (cin >> a >> unit)
    {
        // check if this is the first number entered
        if (numbers.size() == 0)
        {
            a = funconvert(a, unit);
            b = a;
            numbers.push_back(a);
            numbers.push_back(b);
        }
        else
        {
            //assign a and b to the last two numbers in a vector
            a = funconvert(a, unit);
            numbers.push_back(a);
            a = numbers[(numbers.size() - 1)];
            b = numbers[(numbers.size() - 2)];
            // numbers.erase(numbers.begin()); // enable if desire to keep the vector empty
        }

        // find out which variable is larger and smaller
        if (a > b && (a/b-1) >= 0.01)
        {
            smallest = b;
            largest = a;
            printresult(smallest, largest);
        }
        else if (a < b && (b / a - 1) >= 0.01)
        {
            smallest = a;
            largest = b;
            printresult(smallest, largest);
        }
        else if ((a / b - 1) < 0.01 && (a / b - 1) != 0.00 || (b / a - 1) < 0.01 && (a / b - 1) != 0.00)
        {
            cout << "the nubers are almost equal\n";
        }
        else
            cout << a << " equals " << b << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You declare that `printresult` will return a `string`, but your body returns an `int`. Instead, it looks like it should be `void printresult(...)` since you don't have anything to return?

Comment: Why would you return `0` from a function that is expected to return a `string`?

Comment: @AndyG Even thought now retrospectively it makes little sense, I did it so that my program will compile and maybe this way I will be able to trace my error logically. Needless to say, that did not work out. Thanks for your input, it helped a lot! Now I will know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `return 0`, the C++ standard library attempts to use the `std::string` constructor from a `const char*`. But that constructor requires you to supply a valid address to a nul-terminated character buffer else the program behaviour is *undefined*.

To fix, change the function to a `void` return type:

`void printresult(double smallest, double largest)`

and drop the `return` statement in the function body.

Also consider replacing the idiosyncratic `return x = x;` with `return x;`

Comment: It did not make sense to me to place `int` or another of this sort, however `string` was the closest one to my logic (I am new to programming). Now I will know that void is to be used in such cases. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your `printresult` returns a `std::string` which you initialize by 0. It calls the following constructor

```
basic_string( const CharT* s,
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

And it is [undefined behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) to pass it anything other than a valid buffer address.

> Constructs the string with the contents initialized with a copy of the
>   null-terminated character string pointed to by s. The length of the
>   string is determined by the first null character. The behavior is
>   undefined if s does not point at an array of at least
>   Traits::length(s)+1 elements of CharT, including the case when s is a
>   null pointer.

Consider yourself lucky your standard library implementation asserts on this.